# What is a word for someone who hates to see others hurt or hates to cause pain to others?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives, synonyms

I'm trying to find an adjective that describes someone who hates to inflict pain on others. This character doesn't want to tell his relative how an event went because he knows the outcome of the event would hurt his relative (if that makes any sense at all). I'm trying to use a word other than selfless because I feel I have it used it enough and I don't want to make it repetitive.

Comment: Empathetic? Sympathetic?

Comment: Why do you not want to use the word *selfless*? Please edit your question to add more description of the kind of word you want, the words you have already considered, and why you have rejected them. You can see a checklist in the tag information for [single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).

Comment: Writing advice requests are out of scope.
Word or phrase requests are out of scope, unless they are expert-level, particularly interesting, unique, and thought-provoking, and show effort and research.
For an introduction to the site, take the [Tour]. For help writing a good question, see [ask].

Answer (score 1):

## Humane

I feel the word 'Humane' would fit.

> Humane (Adjective)
>
> 1. characterized by tenderness, compassion, and sympathy for people and animals, especially for the suffering or distressed: humane
>    treatment of prisoners.
> 2. acting in a manner that causes the least harm to people or animals: humane trapping of stray pets.

Reference: http://www.dictionary.com/browse/humane

Answer (score 0):

This may help: ***softie/softy***

[From TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/softy):

> **softy** or **softie**:   n. pl. softies *Informal*
>
> 1. A person regarded as weak or sentimental.
> 2. A person who finds it *difficult to* punish or *be strict*.

[From oxforddictionaries.com](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/softie):

> **softie**
>
> (also **softy**) NOUN (plural softies)
>
> *informal* A soft-hearted, weak, or sentimental person: she is too much of a softie to fire anyone
>
> **More example sentences:**
>
> Giles was ridiculed all over again as a cry-baby and a big softie.
>
> His temper in the office could be fiery and he might seem a bit hot
> and bothered but deep down he was a softy.
>
> Hardchannel is a softy at heart, however, with a fondness for
> traditional American musicals, so that he tends to burst into song at
> unlikely moments.